# python not accessing normals rotation

Tags: python, scripting

for the past few weeks I've been trying to write a python script that accesses the rotation of the custom split normals on my object. I then want it to transfer the x,y and z rotation of the custom split normals to the coordinates of separate uv maps. I've managed to access the split normals using calc_normals_split but now I'm having trouble isolating and transferring the xyz coordinates to the uv maps.Here is the python script I'm using.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data

# calc split normals
me.calc_normals_split()

normal = Loop.normal
ob.data.uv_layers["xy"].data[loop.normal].uv = (normal.x, normal.y)
ob.data.uv_layers["z"].data[loop.normal].uv = (normal.z, 0)
```

I need to transfer the normal x,y, and z coordinates to separate uv maps because uv maps are 2 dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

The code from your last question was closer. All you needed was to calc_normal_split and to use the loop.normal instead of the vertex.normal.

```py
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object

ob.data.calc_normals_split()

for loop in ob.data.loops:
    normal = loop.normal
    ob.data.uv_layers["XY"].data[loop.index].uv = (normal.x, normal.y)
    ob.data.uv_layers["ZW"].data[loop.index].uv = (normal.z, 0)
```

Note that this calculates and stores the normals of the mesh as it looks *in edit mode*, ie. *before* any modifiers. Your armature modifier for example will change the normals.

You can swap out the reconstructed normal for the actual normal in the shader to see that it works.

[image: Swapping out reconstruction for Geometry>Normal in the shader]

Comment: Perhaps this could be consolidated as answer  to previous question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240587/calculating-split-normals-using-python and this one could be closed as dupe. (or vice versa)