# How to get split normal of selected vertex in python

Tags: python, mesh, add-on, vertices, normals

I'm trying to get the split normal direction value of a selected vertex using python, but I'm not being able to do it.
All help is apreciated

Comment: [Calculating split normals using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240587/calculating-split-normals-using-python) ... [How to set custom vertex normals for certain vertices using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165115/how-to-set-custom-vertex-normals-for-certain-vertices-using-python]) ... [There is a way to add custom split normal use Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104650/there-is-a-way-to-add-custom-split-normal-use-python-api)

Comment: Sorry but none of those links answers what I asked. Just need to get the Vector3 direction of a single selected vertex's split normal. I'm not looking to set or change anything of the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Vertices do not have split normals. Each *corner of a face* has a split normal. That's what "split" means, it's how there can be different normals on either side of a sharp edge. For example, look at a flat-shaded cube. There are three split normals at each single vertex, one for each face.

[image: Flat shaded cube showing three split normals per corner]

Blender internally calls a corner of a face a *loop*. To get the split normal for a loop, you do this

```
# This calculates all split normals, you must do this once
# before you can access them or they'll all be (0,0,0)
mesh.calc_normals_split()

# Get split normal for i-th loop
mesh.loops[i].normal
```

This works for a Mesh (object mode). Accessing split normals for a bmesh (Edit mode) is unsupported ([ref](https://developer.blender.org/T45151)).

If want you want is a list of all split normals at all selected vertices, you would have to iterate through all the loops

```
mesh.calc_normals_split()

split_normals = [
    loop.normal
    for loop in mesh.loops
    if mesh.vertices[loop.vertex_index].selected
]
```